# Flexible column layout does not work when Two Way binding

Tags: layout, data-binding, sapui5

My app has a flexible column layout with the list report displayed initially, and then switch to two columns when I click on an entry in the list report. This works fine so far with one way binding with backend model. But when I switch to two way binding then the click on entry does not show the second column. I am using the following code to switch the layout to two-column.

```
this.byId("flexibleColumnLayout").setLayout(sLayout);
```

Inside the `setLayout()` , I see some code that speaks about two-way binding. I am not an expert though to understand that level.

Anyone has fixed such an encounter? Appreciate your help. Thanks...

```
this.byId("flexibleColumnLayout").setLayout(sLayout);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is resovled. The setLayout method is triggering some code where is going through some two way binding check and did try property binding checking against backend model, which is not correct. Instead binding the control to local json model did work. Thank you all!